# How trustworthy is KMSpico?

Tags: malware, windows-10, trust

KMSpico is a very common tool to crack Windows. It is considered malware by many malware/virus detection programs. Even so, it is very popular as far as I've seen.

Download links I found:

- https://kmspico10.com/
- https://official-kmspico.com/
- https://www.kmspico2k.com/
- https://kmspico.co/

With so many "official websites" and many more possible download sources, it's hard to know which download(s) can be trusted.

I am aware that ALL such software are dangerous (probably also illegal if it cracks software). I'm still going to try and use it on Windows 10 because (1) I don't want to spend money on Windows and (2) every IT store (including those legit and large) in my area installs cracked Windows by default.

Comment: "Everyone's doing it" is not a legal argument though.

Answer (score 4):

## It's not verifiable.

At least, without putting in effort to reverse-engineer the software.

As it turns out, "How trustworthy is *[this software]*?" is in general an incredibly tough question to answer. The problem is that it's hard to verify, especially if no source-code is present. Even if source code were present, how can you know that the pre-built version would correspond to that source code?

In the "best case" scenario, the program is benign and does what it's supposed to do (which is still illegal and may get you into trouble).

In the most likely case, the program will do what it's advertised to do, plus a number of other things. Which things? That depends on the author.

Consider the following: **Would you let a random stranger have admin access to your computer if they gave you 139 USD for it?**